# Seeing different blacks on playing same video on tv from different devices

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, screencasts

So I have following devices

VA panel TV
Anycast dongle
Hdmi cable
OLED display phone
IPS display phone
Laptop

I am seeing different picture on following three arrangements

1. OLED phone -> anycast -> TV

The video is mostly black losing complete information where there are dark places. I guess 15-20% picture is black.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWMHb.jpg

2. IPS phone ->anycast -> TV

The picture dramatically improves on most of the places which are not too dark.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8es2.jpg

3. Laptop -> HDMI -> TV

The picture improves even more where I can see details even in dark places.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGv78.jpg

So I want to understand why I am seeing so many variations and how can I correct that.

Comment: it is unclear exactly what mechanism is being used for the anycast (anycast is a network protocol), but this looks like a gamma issue. Probably the image is being passed, but the contrast has been calibrated for the OLED etc

Comment: Basically it's a profiling issue. You'll need to check your TV's manual for how to compensate for each, then hope you have enough preset spaces to save them all. The laptop will be easiest overall to deal with because you can actually hang a colorimeter off it & accurately measure.